# Include unknowns in percentage calculation but not p-values when using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is it possible to have the NAs included in the percentage calculation but not in the chi-square/Fisher's exact test when using gtsummary? I know that I could change the NAs to "Unknown" in the data and have them included in the percentage but I would like to exclude them when calculating the p-value:

```
animal<-c("dog",NA,"cat","bird","cat","dog",NA)
color<-c("blue","red","blue","red","red","blue")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(animal,color))

table1 <- 
  tbl_summary(
  df %>% select(animal,color),
  by = color)%>%
  add_p() 
  

table1
```

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 different table options for you here. Choose the one you want!

```
animal<-c("dog",NA,"cat","bird","cat","dog",NA)
color<-c("blue","red","blue","red","red","blue")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(animal,color))


tbl1 <-
  df %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = color,
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  add_n(statistic = "{n_miss} ({p_miss}%)") %>%
  modify_header(n = "**Missing**")


tbl2 <-
  df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(animal = forcats::fct_explicit_na(factor(animal))) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = color, 
    include = animal, 
    label = list(animal = "animal")
  ) %>%
  list(tbl1 %>% modify_column_hide(c(n, all_stat_cols()))) %>%
  tbl_merge(tab_spanner = FALSE)

tbl2
```

[image: tbl2]